# Traer los registros que no estén asociados en la tabla de JOIN

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo el Modelo Maestro y el modelo Transaccion

```
class Maestro < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :transacciones
end

class Transaccion < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Necesito traerme todos los maestros que no tengan transacciones.

Intenté esto, pero no funciona:

```
Maestro.left_outer_joins(:transacciones)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vas bien encaminado, solo te faltó poner la condición que filtra las transacciones donde no está asociado un maestro:

```
Maestro.left_outer_joins(:transacciones).where(transaccions: {maestro_id: nil})
```